# if statement colors in listview

Tags: android, listview, scroll

With this statement, inserted into the listview,

```
  public View getView(int pos, View child, ViewGroup parent) {
        SharedPreferences prefs = mContext.getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String anno = prefs.getString(ANNO, "2014");
        String malattia = prefs.getString(MUTUA, "M");
        String ferie_1 = prefs.getString(FERIE, "F");
        String par_1 = prefs.getString(PAR, "PAR");
        Holder mHolder;
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
        //text in which you want to find "M"
        if (child == null) {
            layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            child = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
            mHolder = new Holder();
            mHolder.txt_notes = (TextView) child.findViewById(R.id.txt_notes);
            mHolder.txt_mese = (TextView) child.findViewById(R.id.txt_mese);
            mHolder.txt_giorni = (TextView) child.findViewById(R.id.txt_giorni);
            mHolder.txt_turno = (TextView) child.findViewById(R.id.txt_turno);
            mHolder.txt_ore = (TextView) child.findViewById(R.id.txt_ore);
            mHolder.txt_id = (TextView) child.findViewById(R.id.txt_id);
            child.setTag(mHolder);
        } else {
            mHolder = (Holder) child.getTag();
        }
        mHolder.txt_giorni.setText(giorniName.get(pos));
        mHolder.txt_turno.setText(turnoName.get(pos));
        mHolder.txt_ore.setText(oreName.get(pos));
        mHolder.txt_id.setText(dataName.get(pos));

        mHolder.txt_giorni.setText(giorniName.get(pos));
        mHolder.txt_turno.setText(turnoName.get(pos));
        mHolder.txt_ore.setText(oreName.get(pos));
        mHolder.txt_id.setText(dataName.get(pos));

        String Turni = turnoName.get(pos);
        String Mese = meseName.get(pos);
        String Data = dataName.get(pos);
        String Giorni = giorniName.get(pos);
        String Notes = notesName.get(pos);


        if (Turni != null)
        if (Turni.equals(""+malattia)){
            mHolder.txt_turno.setTextColor(Color.RED);
            mHolder.txt_ore.setTextColor(Color.RED);
        } else 
        if (Turni.equals(""+par_1)){
            mHolder.txt_turno.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
            mHolder.txt_ore.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
        } else
        if (Turni.equals(""+ferie_1)){
                mHolder.txt_turno.setTextColor(Color.YELLOW);
                mHolder.txt_ore.setTextColor(Color.YELLOW);
        } else  
            mHolder.txt_turno.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        if (Notes != null) {
               if (!Notes.equalsIgnoreCase("")){
                   mHolder.txt_notes.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                   mHolder.txt_notes.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
                   mHolder.txt_notes.setText("Nota");
               } else {
                   mHolder.txt_notes.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
               } 
            }


        if (Giorni != null) 
        if (Giorni.equals("Sab")){
            mHolder.txt_giorni.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFA500"));
        } else 
            if (Giorni.equals("Dom")
                    {
            mHolder.txt_giorni.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        } else
            mHolder.txt_giorni.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);

        if (Giorni != null) 
            if (Giorni.equals("Sab")){
                mHolder.txt_id.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFA500"));
        } else 
            if (Giorni.equals("Dom"){
            mHolder.txt_id.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        } else
            mHolder.txt_id.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);



        return child;
    }



    public class Holder {
        TextView txt_notes;
        TextView txt_mese;
        TextView txt_giorni;
        TextView txt_turno;
        TextView txt_ore;
        TextView txt_id;
    }
}
```

I should get the `texview txt_notes` with green background if the database contains some data, while if it is empty, it should be red. 
My problem is that if I make the scrolling of the `listview`, one by one all the `TextView` turn green, if I do a refresh of the entire class back to the right place. 
How do I fix this problem?

Comment: I do not think the problem is in the posted code, can you add full code? There seem to be a mess with the mHolder data and the way listviews work.

Comment: This part of the code in question

Answer (score 0):

The `Holder` and `setTag`, `getTag` seems fine! So the only reason that may cause the faulty recycle is the `null` values at your data.

So if one of these becomes `null`

```
    String Turni = turnoName.get(pos);
    String Mese = meseName.get(pos);
    String Data = dataName.get(pos);
    String Giorni = giorniName.get(pos);
    String Notes = notesName.get(pos);
```

then the `setTextColor` or `setBackgroundColor` is not being called for the `TextView`, as a result it keeps the last known recycled from the `Holder` (not the one set at xml). To avoid that you should "hardcode" the color in all cases.

```
if (Notes != null) {
    if (!Notes.equalsIgnoreCase("")){
       mHolder.txt_notes.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
       mHolder.txt_notes.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
       mHolder.txt_notes.setText("Nota");
    } else {
       mHolder.txt_notes.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
    } 
} else {
    mHolder.txt_notes.setBackgroundColor(your_default_color_here);
}
```

---

If `null` and `empty` is handled the same way you can use `TextUtils.isEmpty(Notes)` which return true in both cases.